# Trying to use Guid from C# as primary key in Cassandra

Tags: c#, cassandra, nosql, datastax, cassandra-3.0

I am currently working on my NoSQL project and I have two databases Cassandra and Redis (I am using Redis for caching). Now with Redis I have one list and I serialize my custom object using DataContract, but when it comes to Cassandra I am struggling since I am trying to somehow insert Guid in Cassandra table, in which I am using uuid as primary key. I have searched the Internet and all I could find was that Guid is Cassandra's uuid type of data. I have inserted uuid using now() in Cassandra so I am wondering if I could somehow invoke that now() from C# or if I can somehow convert Guid to uuid. Any help or reference is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per [driver documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/3.4/features/datatypes/), `uuid` is already mapped into `Guid` and back... So you can simply [bind your variable into corresponding placeholder in statement](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/3.4/features/parametrized-queries/).

Comment: Thanks, this was an obvious one but could not find the solution. Thank you, once again.

Comment: See https://github.com/datastax/csharp-driver/blob/master/src/samples/CassandraSamples/ForumRepository.cs as example of working with `Guid`

Comment: I didn't see this earlier. Thank you for sharing.